# Understanding the Big-O of this summation

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I understand the Big-O for this summation is $O(n^3)$.
I tried to break it down algebraically and I seem to be getting $O(n^3):$

SUMMATION:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i(n-i)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n (n-i)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n i \cdot (\sum_{i=1}^n  n- \sum_{i=1}^n i)\\
&= \frac{n(n+1)}2\cdot (n^2 \cdot n(n+1)/2) = O(n^4).\\
\end{align}

Might someone help point out my error here?
Thanks!

Comment: The very first step – the sum of a product does not equal the product of the sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is wrong: $\sum_{i=1}^ni(n-i)$ is **not** equal to $\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)\right)$. In fact

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^ni(n-i)&=\sum_{i=1}^nin-\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\\
&=n\sum_{i=1}^ni-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\\
&=\frac{n^2(n+1)}2-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\\
&=\frac{3n^3+3n^2-(2n^3+3n^2+n)}6\\
&=\frac{n^3-n}6\\
&\in O(n^3)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @KatieMelosto: You’re welcome!